# does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(n)n!}{n^n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I get to the point, using the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{\sin(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)^n\sin(n)}$$

and I know I can take a $1/e$ out but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Recall that $n!\sim e^{-n} n^{n+1/2}\sqrt {2\pi}$.

Comment: Use ratio test only on positive series.

Comment: In fact,$\{\frac{\sin(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)^n\sin(n)}: n \in \mathbb {N}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb {R}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges absolutely:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{|\sin(n)|n!}{n^n} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n!}{n^n}. $$

Then, using the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{(n+1)!n^n}{n!(n+1)^{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty }\left ( \frac{n}{n+1} \right )^{n} = e^{-1}<1. $$

So the series converges

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You need dollar signs at the beginning and end of you code for it to render. Regards,

Comment: There's a typo in the last limit.

Comment: last limit should equal 1/e

Answer (score 1):

We know (ratio test) that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$ is convergent and we have $|\sin{n}\frac{n!}{n^n}|\leq \frac{n!}{n^n}$ So the series converges

Comment: what happened to the sin(n+1)

Comment: I used the ratio test for the series without sine and then used comparison

Comment: Without the ratio test: $\frac{n!}{n^n} \le 1\cdot \frac{2\cdot 1}{n\cdot n}=\frac{2}{n^2}, n\ge 2.$ Because $\sum 1/n^2<\infty,$ the series converges absolutley.

Answer (score 1):

just bound away the trig functionL $\sin x <|\sin x|<1$ and the rest follows by 1)Stirling approximation of factorial or 2) slightly more sophisticated integral bounding